# View Desktop version on mobile site?

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile, jquery-mobile, browser-detection

I have my main site redirect to a mobile version if your view it from you mobile device, i wanted to use media queries but that was not an option for this site. On the mobile version i wanted to implement a "View Desktop Version". 

However i am unsure of the correct/best way to do this. I am using the Dectect mobile browser plugin from 
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com.
 If the plugin returns true - meaning you are viewing from a mobile browser - then the main site redirects you. How can i add a `"View Desktop Version"` button and bypass the detection plugin?

Thanks guys

Comment: What language are you using for the Detect Mobile Browser script?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to set a cookie to remember the current state.

In your main site, your code can be updated to something like this (pseudocode):

```
show_desktop_site = $.cookie('show_desktop_site') AND NOT IsMobileBrowser;
```

`IsMobileBrowser` would be the response from the detectmobilebrowsers.com script.

`$.cookie('show_desktop_site')` is a jQuery Cookie set in the mobile site when a user elected to go and view the desktop site. See e.g. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie - many options are out there.

You can redirect the user based on `show_desktop_site`.